# ExtJS 4 - Popup on cellclick in grid panel is not displayed

Tags: extjs, popup, gridpanel

I have a Problem to open a popup window on cellclick.
When i click on the cell everything overlaid grey, but the window is not displayed.

The code is in the follow. Any idea why the new Window is not displayed?

Thanks and Regards.

```
var win = Ext.widget('window', {
                 title: 'Contact Us',
                 closeAction: 'hide',
                 width: 400,
                 height: 400,
                 minHeight: 400,
                 layout: 'fit',
                 resizable: true,
                 modal: true,
                 //items: form
      });


     Ext.define('File',{
         extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
         fields: [
             {name: 'file_id'},
             {name: 'file_input_filename'},
             {name: 'file_type'},
             {name: 'lc_status'},
             {name: 'file_input_date'}
         ]
     });

     // create the Data Store
     var overviewStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
         model: 'File',
         autoLoad: true,
         proxy: {
             type: 'ajax',
             url: 'FileOverview',
             reader: {
                 type: 'xml',
                 // records will have an "Item" tag
                 record: 'Row',
                 idProperty: 'file_id',
                 totalRecords: '@total'
             }
         }
     });

     // create the grid
     var gridOverview = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
         store: overviewStore,
         id: 'OverviewGridPanelId',
         columns: [
             {text: "ID", flex: 1, dataIndex: 'file_id', sortable: true},
             {text: "Filename", width: 180, dataIndex: 'file_input_filename', sortable: true},
             {text: "Filetyp", width: 180, dataIndex: 'file_type', sortable: true},
             {text: "Status", width: 180, dataIndex: 'lc_status', sortable: true},
             {text: "Imported", width: 115, dataIndex: 'file_input_date', sortable: true}

         ],
         renderTo:'binding-example',
         width: 1200,
         height: 650,

     });


     gridOverview.on('cellclick', function(table, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {
      var masterIndex = rowIndex;
      //openDialog(record.get('file_id'));

      Ext.Msg.alert('locked grid click');
      win.show();

     });


 }
```

Comment: I've put your code into a Fiddle (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1cmb) and it works as expected. Is there other code that's missing from what you posted?

Comment: You may have issues with css... try to build your application files again and clean your browser and check again.

Comment: There is no other Code. I will check if the rebuild of the application and the browser cleanup helps.

Comment: Does an error occur in the browser console?

Comment: Still same issue with cleared browser cache. @Alexander now error occur in the browser console.